# Would GNU Make automatically add extra prerequisite?

Tags: c++, build, makefile

The following example snippet is from *"Managing Projects with GNU Make(3rd edition)"* p.21.

```
count_words: counter.o lexer.o -lfl
```

The author says that `make` will automatically add `count_words.o` to prerequisite list by implicit rule. Quoted:

> ..., make identifies four prerequisites: count_words.o (this prerequisite is missing from the makefile, but is provided by the implicit rule), counter.o, lexer.o, and -lfl.

However, my test doesn't conform to that. Here is my test:

```
prog: abc.o
    @echo $^
abc.o:
    @echo abc.o built.
prog.o:
    @echo prog.o bulit.
```

The output after running `make` is:

> abc.o built.
>
> abc.o

`make` didn't seek for `prog.o` for the target `prog`.
What's the problem? Is there something wrong with my test?

By the way, my test is on `Cygwin` with `GNU Make 4.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gave a recipe for your `prog` target. The author didn't for the `count_words` target. That's the difference.

The author was counting on the built in `%: %.o` rule to take effect. You overrode that with your rule.

Remove the `@echo $^` from the `prog` recipe and try again.